Selecting number of rows at a sample rate over a time range in big query
I have timestamp rows and I want to query over time interval [t1,t2] where t2-t1 can be few hours of span. I want to count the number of rows in this range but I want the output say where the rows are counted at 15 minutes interval.
So if t2-t1 is 120 minutes, I expect 8 rows in output and the number of times rows occurred in the 15 minute windows.
Not very clear on how to do that with Range functions



username
time_column




user1
13:10


user1
13:12


user2
13:14


user1
13:18


user1
13:20


user1
13:22


user1
13:50


user1
13:55



So in above example for user1 say between the hours of 13:00 and 14:00, I want the data as below



username
time_value
counted_value




user1
13:00
3


user1
13:15
3


user1
13:30
0


user1
13:45
2




Please provide example data and expected results

@BartMcEndree added a sample input and output

Why to do this in SQL? It's of course possible, but would be much easier using your application.

You could use generate_range_array to break your 2 hour range down into 15 minute increments, and then unnest to derive a table of 15 minute range increments:
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(generate_range_array(RANGE(TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 11:00:00'), INTERVAL '15' MINUTE, TRUE)) as time_range


+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                             time_range                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| "[2024-10-31 09:00:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 09:15:00.000000 UTC)" |
| "[2024-10-31 09:15:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 09:30:00.000000 UTC)" |
| "[2024-10-31 09:30:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 09:45:00.000000 UTC)" |
| "[2024-10-31 09:45:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 10:00:00.000000 UTC)" |
| "[2024-10-31 10:00:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 10:15:00.000000 UTC)" |
| "[2024-10-31 10:15:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 10:30:00.000000 UTC)" |
| "[2024-10-31 10:30:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 10:45:00.000000 UTC)" |
| "[2024-10-31 10:45:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 11:00:00.000000 UTC)" |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------+

You can then join this to your main table to find rows that fall between each range.
Edit to add:
Using this with your table would look something like:
WITH time_ranges AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST(generate_range_array(RANGE(TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 11:00:00'), INTERVAL '15' MINUTE, TRUE)) as time_range
)
SELECT tr.time_range, count(*) as count_of_users
FROM time_ranges tr
  LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table yt
    ON RANGE_CONTAINS(tr.time_range, yt.time_column)
GROUP BY tr.time_range

Some faked data that you can just copy and paste and run directly:
WITH your_table AS
(
/* faking up a version of your table*/
SELECT 0 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:14:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 1 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:59:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 2 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 11:36:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 3 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:44:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 4 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:58:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 5 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:45:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 6 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:04:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 7 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:44:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 8 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:15:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 9 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:31:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 10 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:27:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 11 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:54:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 12 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:31:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 13 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:05:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 14 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:03:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 15 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 11:09:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 16 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:21:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 17 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:06:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 18 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:05:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 19 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:02:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 20 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:03:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 21 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 11:25:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 22 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:38:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 23 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:31:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 24 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:54:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 25 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 11:37:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 26 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:14:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 27 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:08:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 28 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:49:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 29 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:10:00+00' as time_column
UNION ALL SELECT 30 as username, TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 10:29:00+00' as time_column
)
,time_ranges AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM UNNEST(generate_range_array(RANGE(TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 09:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2024-10-31 11:00:00'), INTERVAL '15' MINUTE, TRUE)) as time_range
)
SELECT tr.time_range, count(*) as count_of_users
FROM time_ranges tr
  LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table yt
    ON RANGE_CONTAINS(tr.time_range, yt.time_column)
GROUP BY tr.time_range

Which will spit out:
+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|                            time_range                            | count_of_users |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| [2024-10-31 09:00:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 09:15:00.000000 UTC) |              4 |
| [2024-10-31 09:15:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 09:30:00.000000 UTC) |              1 |
| [2024-10-31 09:30:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 09:45:00.000000 UTC) |              3 |
| [2024-10-31 09:45:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 10:00:00.000000 UTC) |              3 |
| [2024-10-31 10:00:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 10:15:00.000000 UTC) |              7 |
| [2024-10-31 10:15:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 10:30:00.000000 UTC) |              4 |
| [2024-10-31 10:30:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 10:45:00.000000 UTC) |              3 |
| [2024-10-31 10:45:00.000000 UTC, 2024-10-31 11:00:00.000000 UTC) |              3 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+


Thank you but trying to understand how will the join for a range and an exact timestamp work actually? Because I need to do count for overlapping time in a range and also put the timestamp

I've updated my answer with some examples to help clarify.
